# CSV product Import stuck on Please wait..." hang

Tags: magento2, php, database, csv

I have a problem with **Magento 2** import section.

I am trying to **import** a **product from CSV**, the page stop loading but the **loading icon** is always present and Magento don't check data.

what is the problem? I haven't getting any **error** in the web **console**. The server is ok, other functions work correctly.

What is the problem? Please help me to solve.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share csv which you are using for import?

Comment: Share Screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

A common issue I got in the past which is `I opened the export CSV file by using Excel on MacOs and I saved it.`

The solution for this is `In excel save as "Windows Comma Separated (.csv)"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case for this problem; I ended up learning this was caused by the module Magento_Downloadable being disabled.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try with 2-3 records one time.